# Extract variable policy not working

Tags: documentation, apigee

I have configured my extract variable policy to the following

```
<ExtractVariables name="ExtractURIVariables">
    <URIPath>
        <Pattern>/{username}/age/{age}/*</Pattern>
    </URIPath>
</ExtractVariables>
```

but when it executes I cannot see the username and age variables set .

Answer (score 0):

Your policy works correctly, but it is expecting a URL like the following:

{proxybase}/bob/age/35/somethinghere

because the /* is not optional.

It will not match
{proxybase}/bob/age/35

You can use the following:

```
<ExtractVariables name="ExtractURIVariables">
    <URIPath>
        <Pattern>/{username}/age/{age}</Pattern>
        <Pattern>/{username}/age/{age}/*</Pattern>
    </URIPath>
</ExtractVariables>
```

When more than one pattern is supplied, the first match will be selected.

The updated policy would match

```
{proxybase}/bob/age/35
{proxybase}/bob/age/35/somethinghere
```

If you want to match any number of following URI levels, use two asterisks instead of one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I cannot see the variables assigned in the "variable got" field when the policy is executed

Comment: They should show up in the Variables Set section of the trace. I tested your policy and it works for me, so it might be a different issue with the proxy. If you post the full proxy somewhere, I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Using the trace tool and your policy, I see Variables Got shows
"proxy.pathsuffix: /bob/age/14/somethinghere", and Variables Set shows "username: bob" and "age: 14"